# Can we capture the web service call out request and web service call out response times?

Tags: webservices

Can we capture the web service call out request and web service call out response times.I am able to see these times in debug logs.But i am unable to capture these time.Could you please help on this. 
Please find below screen shot.
User-added image[image]
Need to capture the call out request and call out response time in diffrent stings.
Could you please help on this.

Comment: Please add your code to your question so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can put simple System.Now() before and after the call-out statement.

Example

```
    public sendSMS()
    {
        DateTime t = System.Now();
        // Do Webservice Callout
        // .... callout statement
        DateTime t2 = System.Now();
        // perform operation according to two datetime received.
    }
```